# react native android toolbar shifts down and status bar loses color

Tags: android, react-native, toolbar, statusbar

I'm using a setup very similar to the F8 open source app, where I have a root component that lays out the app as such:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={commonStyles.container}>
    <StatusBar
      backgroundColor="rgb(122,77,246)"
      barStyle="light-content"
    />
    <AppNavigator
      ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }}
      navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
        state: this.props.nav,
      })} />
    <PushNotificationController />
  </View>
)
}
```

The StatusBar is imported directly from React-Native, and the AppNavigator is a simple StackNavigator const.

The issue I'm seeing is that randomly (although usually when the app loads particularly slowly or is restarted while being brought from the background) the status bar color goes away, and the ToolbarAndroid shifts down.

Without the issue:

[image: Before the problem]

With the issue:

[image: After bringing app from background and it restarts]

I define the Toolbar using the following method, also from F8 app.

```
class HeaderAndroid extends Component {

render() {
    const { leftItem, title, rightItem } = this.props;
return (
  <View style={styles.toolbarContainer}>
    <ToolbarAndroid
      navIcon={leftItem && leftItem.icon}
      onIconClicked={leftItem && leftItem.onPress}
      titleColor='white'
      backgroundColor="rgb(122,77,246)"
      actions={this.props.actions}
      style={styles.toolbar}
      onActionSelected={this.props.onActionClicked()}
      title={title} />
  </View>
     )
   }
}

var STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 24;
var HEADER_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 44 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT : 56 + STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  toolbarContainer: {
    paddingTop: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
  },
  toolbar: {
    height: HEADER_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
  },
}
```

I think the issue has something to do with the way I define the padding of the top of the toolbar, but it's done the same as in F8 and I see no issues with that app.

If anyone has run into this issue before and fixed it, I'd love some help.